# Unable to get MAX time inside join but with distinct id MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables to get desired output(latest filepath) :-

1. Events Table [having event Id]
2. Event_media Table [having event Id,media Id and creation_time]
3. Media Table [having media Id and filepath]

> I want to get- all distinct events with their filepath where creation_time of event media Table is MAX such that i can have all events with their updated filepath

MySQL Query:-

```
select e.event_id, m.filepath, em.creation_time as latest from event e join event_media em on e.event_id=em.event_id join media m on em.media_id = m.media_id where em.creation_time=(select MAX(em.creation_time) from event_media where em.event_id =e.event_id);
```

Output :-

```
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| event_id | filepath                                                                           | latest              |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|  1000055 | http://localhost:3000/static/images/glasoimage/event1.jpg                          | 2017-07-06 02:06:30 |
|  1000056 | http://localhost:3000/static/images/glasoimage/event2.jpg                          | 2017-07-06 02:15:15 |
|  1000058 | http://localhost:3000/static/images/glasoimage/event3.jpg                          | 2017-07-06 02:22:17 |
|  1000059 | http://localhost:3000/static/uploads/media/upload_b46a5d6f37f1c77a17b87fcbe5ccb975 | 2017-07-06 02:23:17 |
|  1000066 | http://localhost:3000/static/images/glasoimage/event6.jpg                          | 2017-07-06 17:10:59 |
|  1000057 | http://localhost:3000/static/uploads/media/upload_12b7a15dfae2ce4f7864c957b8ecf5a6 | 2017-07-06 02:20:52 |
|  1000062 | http://localhost:3000/static/images/glasoimage/event4.jpg                          | 2017-07-06 16:45:22 |
|  1000063 | http://localhost:3000/static/images/glasoimage/event5.jpg                          | 2017-07-06 16:47:30 |
|  1000071 | http://localhost:3000/static/uploads/media/upload_d00ab7878fcf6bacdbf800249678b818 | 2017-07-15 14:10:36 |
|  1000071 | http://localhost:3000/static/uploads/media/upload_0c85d276316550ef33e2f274635b99c7 | 2017-07-15 23:42:03 |
|  1000072 | http://localhost:3000/static/images/defaults/default-image.jpg                     | 2017-07-15 23:29:24 |
|  1000073 | http://localhost:3000/static/images/defaults/default-image.jpg                     | 2017-07-16 12:21:57 |
|  1000074 | http://localhost:3000/static/images/defaults/default-image.jpg                     | 2017-07-16 12:25:09 |
|  1000075 | http://localhost:3000/static/images/defaults/default-image.jpg                     | 2017-07-16 13:40:11 |
|  1000076 | http://localhost:3000/static/images/defaults/default-image.jpg                     | 2017-07-16 13:43:10 |
|  1000077 | http://localhost:3000/static/images/defaults/default-image.jpg                     | 2017-07-16 14:04:58 |
|  1000067 | http://localhost:3000/static/images/defaults/default-image.jpg                     | 2017-07-13 21:55:21 |
|  1000068 | http://localhost:3000/static/uploads/media/upload_d32e3685c22232d00602e827f55f6f64 | 2017-07-13 22:45:04 |
|  1000069 | http://localhost:3000/static/uploads/media/upload_e0aab7ea8150ee5e7e1f55d98366e51f | 2017-07-13 22:47:50 |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
19 rows in set (0.18 sec)
```

For event Id 1000071 on line 9 & 10 in output I have two filepath old and new.

> I want the new Filepath only with no duplication of event Id

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a group by and a join on the max

```
  select 
      e.event_id
      , m.filepath
      , em.creation_time as latest 
  from event e 
  join event_media em on e.event_id=em.event_id 
  join media m on em.media_id = m.media_id 
  join ( 
      select 
           event_id
          , MAX(creation_time) as max_time
      from event_media 
      group by event_id
    ) t on t.event_id = em-event_id and em.creation_time = t.max_time
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @scaisEdge, it worked. I don't know how i missed that but thanks once again